# Libra validator connection fails

Tags: cryptocurrency, diem

I've been trying to follow the tutorial at https://developers.libra.org/docs/my-first-transaction

But I get the error

> Not able to connect to validator at ac.testnet.libra.org:80, error RpcFailure(RpcStatus { status: Unavailable, details: Some("Trying to connect an http1.x server") })

when running `./scripts/cli/start_cli_testnet.sh`

Has anyone else gotten this issue? I'm not sure why it wouldn't be available.

Comment: maybe ddosed because of the hype...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be fixed on the new master branch of the github repo. If you're running into this problem, you can just `git pull` and it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as I was on a wifi that I think was blocking the rpc call. I no longer have the error.

Answer (score 0):

After pull "Use git checkout testnet" will fix